# Wanting to keep scroll position when refreshing a partial page template through Rails and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using long polling.  Every time I use AJAX to refresh a page partial inside a div with a scroll bar, the contents are scrolled to the top automatically.  Is there a way to load the partial and keep the scroll position?

```
<div style="height:600px; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <!-- The partial loads here and it is usually greater than 600px, and it can be a different height each time. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the scroll position before the ajax request, and then set it after it is completed:

```
var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
// Your ajax polling code, on success you do the code below.
$(window).scrollTop(scrollPosition);
```

Comment: Much appreciated!  It worked.  And it did not look like the screen was jumping at all.  Thank you.